# Grab Data from firebase with Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue with this code below which has almost verbatim been copied from the Firebase SDK Java docs to work. I'm new to a real language such as Java coming from a webdev background in PHP and JavaScript.

Basically the addListenerForSingleValueEvent isn't firing to give me back data. I noticed this because the system printout doesn't fire thus I assume that the listening event didn't fire.

I suspect that this has to do with my limited knowledge how out the function itself works, like I'm missing some structural knowledge of how the class and functions interact with each other.

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

```
class FireBase {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Fetch the service account key JSON file contents
    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("key.json");

    // Initialize the app with a service account, granting admin privileges
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
        .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
        .setDatabaseUrl("https://ssworks-adwords.firebaseio.com/")
        .build();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    // As an admin, the app has access to read and write all data, regardless of Security Rules
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance()
        .getReference("petitions");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Before Get Value");
            Object document = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            System.out.println(document);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("This didn't work");
        }
    });
}

}
```

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: Nothing, I don't' even see the "Before Get Value" output. So I don't think the function is even firing at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a java program that's invoked on the command line via some class's main function, you have to prevent that main function from returning before the database listener fires.  Otherwise, the program will immediately terminate and the listener will never fire.  It's important to remember that all Firebase listeners are asynchronous, and Firebase manages its own daemon thread for communicating with the server.

For the case of making a simple program wait until a listener triggers, you can use this sort of pattern to block the main thread to wait for the listener:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        System.out.println("onDataChange: " + dataSnapshot);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("onCanceled: " + databaseError);
        latch.countDown();
    }
});
latch.await();
```

Using a CountDownLatch is not your only option. You can do whatever you want to make sure the process doesn't stop, including simply sleeping the main thread for longer than it takes for the listener to fire.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now I need to research wat a CountDownLatch is.

Comment: CountDownLatch a kind of synchronization tool that lets a thread of execution wait for some other things to complete first.  In my case, it's keeping the main thread from continuing until the event listener fires asynchronously in a different thread.  (And if you could accept this answer, I'd appreciate it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the explainer as well. I accepted your answer. Thanks again for your time and expertise.