# Firebase Java Admin SDK - Listensers not working

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I created the firebase project and its working properly from the android application. Then I tried to integrate the same firebase application to my API. I followed the documentation on Firebase website on setting up an Java Admin SDK.

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class NewClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(".\Signage-f5d7a18d6c2c.json");
      FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
          .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
          .setDatabaseUrl("https://signage-7068e.firebaseio.com/")
          .build();
      FirebaseApp initializeApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

      System.out.println("-start-");
      System.out.println(initializeApp.getName());

      FirebaseDatabase defaultDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance());

      defaultDatabase.getReference().child("Client").child("-KkOvAIiASpGaNgzI4Go").getRef().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println("onDataChange");
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.out.println("onCancelled");
         }
      });
      System.out.println(defaultDatabase.getReference().child("Client").push().getKey());
      System.out.println("-end-");
   }
}
```

My output is:

```
-start-
[DEFAULT]
-Kx7lHj7G0wem7R29E7G
-end-
```

It seems the connection to the database is established properly, because the `getKey()` method generates a new key. But the `ValueEventListeners` are not triggering. I've also declared the rules.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Client":{ 
      ".read": "true",
      ".write": "true"
    }
}
```

Here is my database:
[image]

Comment: The `push()` method with no parameters returns locally and doesn't actually connect to the database. Can you try pushing some data instead? A simple: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Client").push().setValue("test");` should work.

Comment: did that. Still nothing happens to the database or neither the `OnComplete listener` is triggering.

Comment: Is there actually data at the location where you're adding the listener: `Client/-KkOvAIiASpGaNgzI4Go`?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548932/grab-data-from-firebase-with-java) answer

Comment: Thanks @JenPerson. That was the problem

Comment: @JenPerson Thanks