# How to write data to firebase with a Java program

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to write data to an existing Firebase database but no data is written.

Is there an example Java program that writes data to a Firebase database somewhere, that I can use?

What I have done sofar is the following:

```
package org.nilostep.bota.dcp.export;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.database.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ReadWriteFirebase {

    private static final String DATABASE_URL = " (the url of my database) ";


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("bota-6e0b33e3f1fe.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount)).setDatabaseUrl("https://bota-313fb.firebaseio.com").build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("testdata");

    Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
    users.put("A", "Jaap");
    System.out.println(users);
    db.setValue(users);

    System.out.println(db);
}
```

}

'testdata' is an existing child under the database root.

SECOND VERSION OF PROGRAM

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream serviceAccount =
            new FileInputStream("bota-6e0b33e3f1fe.json");

    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
            .build();

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DATABASE_URL);
    DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference().child("testdata");
    ref.setValueAsync("I'm writing data", new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null) {
                System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
            }
        }
    });
```

it stops with the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class org.nilostep.bota.dcp.export.ReadWriteFirebase$1
at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:108)
at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(NodeUtilities.java:33)
at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.PriorityUtilities.parsePriority(PriorityUtilities.java:38)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(DatabaseReference.java:241)
at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueAsync(DatabaseReference.java:218)
at org.nilostep.bota.dcp.export.ReadWriteFirebase.main(ReadWriteFirebase.java:44)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Nothing is written to the database.
I have also installed the https://github.com/pronto-it-labs/firebase-demo which is an easy install. This app works but does not write to Firebase either.

Comment: Note that you have to replace your url in john-doe-ctrl.js, jane-doe-ctrl.js and FirebaseService.java

Comment: Can you try adding a completion handler to the `setValue()` call? See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-completion-callback As another lead: what version of the Firebase Admin SDK are you using?

Comment: The admin SDK 5.4.0 :
     <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

Will get back on the other thing a bit later. Thanks, so far.

Comment: I created a second program with your suggestion below the original question. See there for the error message I received when running.

Comment: The behavior changed in version 5.4 of the Admin SDK, which means the program exits before the write completes. Check this answer for a way to make the program wait: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548932/grab-data-from-firebase-with-java

Comment: I actually managed to overwrite a Node, although I don't understand the code, which I find really odd. - Have to think about how to continue with this. Is the API Reference the only doc on Firebase database?

Comment: The link I gave is the guide for the Admin SDK. It's only a few pages, but contains most of the common information. Reading it end to end should take no more than a few hours, and will save you a multitude of that down the line.

Comment: Working on it, thank you @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen what do you think of my answer below ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the

```
CountDownLatch,
latch.countdown(), 
latch.await()
```

which aren't documented.

The following class works.

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Firebase {

    private static final String DATABASE_URL = "YOUR_DB_URL";
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    public Firebase() {
        InputStream serviceAccount = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/bota-6e0b33e3f1fe.json");

        try {
            FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(DATABASE_URL)
                .build();
            FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(DATABASE_URL);

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void update(Object value) {
        update(value, "testdata");
    }

    public void update(Object value, String key) {
        try {
            DatabaseReference ref = firebaseDatabase.getReference(key);
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
            ref.setValue(value, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
                        latch.countDown();
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
            });
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        firebaseDatabase.getApp().delete();
    }
}
```