# strange error with firebase java admin sdk datasnapshot loop don't start when calling a method from another class

Tags: java, firebase, for-loop, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

i have a class DataBase with a method called "query" that basically put all child of node "riferimento" into an arraylist

```
public ArrayList<ContenutoDAO> query(String riferimento)
{
    ArrayList<ContenutoDAO> res=new ArrayList<>();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(riferimento);


    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        private ContenutoDAO temp=null;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                temp=new ContenutoDAO();
                temp.setTipo(ds.child("tipo").getValue(String.class));
                temp.setTitolo(ds.child("titolo").getValue(String.class));
                temp.setValore(ds.child("valore").getValue(String.class));
                res.add(temp);

                System.out.println("prova-prova"); 
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return res;
}
```

When the listener is attached the for loop isn't executed at all untill i call temp.setTipo(...),temp.setTitolo(...) and temp.setValore(...).These methods don't let the for loop been executed.If i delete these metod the for loop works
this is ContenutoDAO class:

```
public class ContenutoDAO {

private SimpleStringProperty tipo;
private SimpleStringProperty titolo;
private SimpleStringProperty valore;


public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo.set(tipo);
}

public void setTitolo(String titolo) {
    this.titolo.set(titolo);
}

public void setValore(String valore) {
    this.valore.set(valore);
}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo.get();
}

public String getTitolo() {
    return titolo.get();
}

public String getValore() {
    return valore.get();
}

public StringProperty tipoProperty() {
    return tipo;
}

public StringProperty titoloProperty() {
    return titolo;
}

public StringProperty valoreProperty() {
    return valore;
}}
```

I tried a lot of solutions like:

1.using string instead of simplestringproperty in ContenutiDAO class

2. filling an arraylist of the datasnapshots and convert it to an arraylist of  ContenutoDAO in another method

   3.put the code of query method inside the constructor of class database (the constructior initialize firebaseapp)

   4.creating 3 araylist of string(one for each child of the node: tipo, titolo and value) then filling it with the values and later fill the arraylist of ContenutiDAO using these data

this is the database structure

-root
 ---music museum
 -----chuck berry
 -------contenuto0
 ------------valore: value
 ------------tipo:   value
 ------------titolo: value
 -------contenuto1
 ------------valore: value
 ------------tipo:   value
 ------------titolo: value

i need to retrive all child of music museum/chuck berry.
Sorry form my bad english i know it's a strange error ,thanks you for the attention.

Comment: Is `riferimento` pointing to the right path? Also catch and log any errors in the `onDataChange()` event listener.

Comment: i solved the problem , it was a stupid error constructor of contenutoDAO did not allocate  the SimpleStringProperty object so when i tried to call the setters NullPointerException was thrown. Thanks for the help it was very dumb

Comment: Reference to the solution of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548932/grab-data-from-firebase-with-java