# I want to connect a Netbeans java application with Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase, netbeans, firebase-admin

I am new to Firebase. I know there is an SDK (Firebase Admin SDK) which allows you to connect a Java application to the Firebase Database. I followed all the instructions given on the Firebase's website ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start ) but still my data is not getting saved in the database. My code is as follows :

```
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FirebaseDBDemo {

public String date_of_birth;
public String full_name;
public String nickname;

public FirebaseDBDemo(String date_of_birth, String full_name) {
    this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
    this.full_name = full_name;
}

public FirebaseDBDemo(String date_of_birth, String full_name, String nickname) {
    this.date_of_birth = date_of_birth;
    this.full_name = full_name;
    this.nickname = nickname;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        // Initializing the SDK

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\NetBeansFirebase\\New\\nbfb-51117-firebase-adminsdk-s2gs4-5b1a87c6b2.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://nbfb-51117.firebaseio.com/")
            .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);



        System.out.println("\n------SDK is Initialized------");



        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/fireblog");

        DatabaseReference usersRef = ref.child("users");
        Map<String, FirebaseDBDemo> users = new HashMap<>();
        users.put("alanisawesome", new FirebaseDBDemo("June 23, 1912", "Alan Turing"));
        users.put("gracehop", new FirebaseDBDemo("December 9, 1906", "Grace Hopper"));

        usersRef.setValueAsync(users);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(""+e);
    }


}
}
```

My build.gradle file is as follows :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

// NetBeans will automatically add "run" and "debug" tasks relying on the
// "mainClass" property. You may however define the property prior executing
// tasks by passing a "-PmainClass=<QUALIFIED_CLASS_NAME>" argument.

// Note however, that you may define your own "run" and "debug" task if you
// prefer. In this case NetBeans will not add these tasks but you may rely on
// your own implementation.
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = 'FirebaseDBDemo'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    // You may define additional repositories, or even remove "mavenCentral()".
    // Read more about repositories here:

}

dependencies {
    // TODO: Add dependencies here ...
    // You can read more about how to add dependency here:

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25'
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You have to wait for the returned `Future` to complete. Otherwise your program will exit before the data is written to the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All interaction between the Firebase SDK and its servers happens asynchronously on a secondary thread. This means the JVM most likely exits before that thread has had a chance to send the data to the database. To prevent that from happening, you'll need to make the main thread wait for the write to the database to complete.

```
final CountDownLatch sync = new CountDownLatch(1);
ref.push().setValue("new value")
   .addOnCompleteListener(new DatabaseReference. CompletionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
       if (databaseError != null) {
         System.out.println("Data could not be saved " + databaseError.getMessage());
       } else {
         System.out.println("Data saved successfully.");
       }
       sync.countDown();
     }
});
sync.await();
```

Also see:

- [Firebase with java (non-android) retrieve information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098006/firebase-with-java-non-android-retrieve-information/37100794#37100794)

Comment: Thanks Frank van Puffelen